# when is memory allocated by new?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dictionary, new-operator

I have the following program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

int  *ar;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int N,i;
    map <int , int> W;
    ar = new int[N+1];
    cin >> N;
    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        cin >> ar[i];
    }
    W[ar[N]]= -1;   
    return 0;
}
```

I give following input to program:

```
6

1 1 2 2 3 4
```

If I compile the above code using g++ -O option (no optimization), I get segabrt at the line

```
W[ar[N]]= -1;
```

Two questions:

1. is it the case that ar[] has not been allocated memory by new? i get the same error if i replace the line by some constant value.

   ```
   W[4] = -1;
   ```
2. is there some kind of initialization required for the map? It usually works without initialization for me.

Comment: You're using `N` before initializing it...

Comment: your code looks more like C than C++ by the way ...

Comment: @user1824407 Ugh. `new` operator, namespaces, etc... That's not quite C.

Comment: @H2CO3 now it's edited ... i was referring to the business logic of the program by the way, I don't know you but dealing directly with POD types reminds me of the C world.

Comment: @user1824407 well, sometimes primitives are just better, you don't need a separate `template NumberIncrementor` with an overloaded `operator++` just in order to increment an int...

Answer (score 7):

You have these two lines backwards:

```
ar = new int[N+1];   // Here the value of 'N' is undefined (random)
                     // So the number of values you get is also random (+1)
cin >> N;
```

You need to load `N` before you use it:

```
cin >> N;
ar = new int[N+1];  // Now N is defined and you get the requested number of values.
```

Comment: But aren't integers on most implementations defaulted to 0?

Comment: @David - From C89 6.5.7: *If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, it is initialized implicitly as if every member that has arithmetic type were assigned 0 and every member that has pointer type were assigned a null pointer constant. If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.*